# Приложение не работает на другом компьютере

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-studio

Собрал решение в Visual studio 2022, SDK NET 6.04, net framework 4.8. Исполняемое приложение собирается из проекта на С#, к нему подключаются два проекта на c++ (для opencv). Все собирается, компилируется без ошибок, работает на моем компе. Переношу все файлы из выходной папки сборки на другой комп. Запускаю приложение все работает нормально до момента вызова методов из проектов С++. Программа зависает напрочь. Пишет ошибку не найдены зависимость или сборка. Естественно установил на этот комп SDK NET 6.04, net framework 4.8. В чем причина не понятно.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как посмотреть все зависимости и найти какой сборки не хватает?
Что использовать? GetReferencedAssmblies()? Или в Visual Studio есть какие то средства?
Может какой то инсталятор, который соберет все в кучу. Спасибо.

---

Приложение не работает на другом компьютере

мастер публикации

[image: мастер публикации]

Comment: Все зависимости должны быть вам известны еще до сборки. Все зависимости находятся руками посредством чтения документации и/или исходного кода проекта. *"Естественно установил на этот комп SDK NET 6.04, net framework 4.8."* - совершенно бессмысленное действие... Для проектов С++ следует начинать с C++ runtime

Comment: Запустите плюсовый экзешник дабл-кликом из проводника. Какие-нибудь ошибки появляются?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Спасибо большое! Помогло) Запустил плюсовой экзешник и вылезла ошибка с недостающим файлом

Comment: @HolyBlackCat не разобрался, как тут можно писать. Можно еще вопрос? нужно построить график, есть несколько значений Х и соответствующих ему Y. Нужно аппроксимировать кривую по этим значениям ну и построить ее на экране. Может есть какие то стандартные библиотеки, функции в С#, C++. Буду благодарен за наводку, ссылку, литературу. Спасибо.

Comment: Это лучше отдельно напишите, кнопкой "задать вопрос" вверху.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете воспользоваться функцией Publish в VisualStudio и в настройках публикации выбрать режиму сборки (Deployment mode) значение Self contained, а также поставить галочку в пункте Produce single file.

Кроме того, необходимо включить в проект дополнительные внешние файлы на C++. В их настройках необходимо также выбрать настройку копирования и поставить значение Always Copy (По умолчанию он не копируется).

В таком случае при компиляции проекта все зависимые сборки будут скопированы вместе с файлом в итоговую папку приложения.

[Подробнее про функцию Publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=vs#publish-a-single-file-app)

Comment: когда нажимаю на опубликовать, у меня появляется совсем другое окно мастера публикации, где нет указанных настроек. Дело в настройках Visual Studio или в типе мастера проектов С#???  


![мастер публикации] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gJxd.png